# Python is not recognising a submodule even with __init__,py

Tags: python, import, module

I made a project that is a collection of code and seperated them to make it easy to publish to PyPi. I have this directory here:

```
foo
|   __init__.py
|
\---coordinates
    |   __init__.py
    |
    \---coordinates
            coordinates.py
            __init__.py
```

However, when i import foo, it does not recognise the coordinates submodule.

```
>>>import foo
>>>dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>>foo.coordinates
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'coordinates'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: with this layout you need to `import foo.coordinates` as well, or add `import coordinates` to `foo/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any point in doing what you are doing.
Try doing `from foo.coordinates.coordinates import coordinates`.

If you still want to do `foo.coordinates` you must add `import [submodule_name]` like `import coordinates` in your `__init__.py`.